# Form text field in nested div not clickable

Tags: php, html, css, forms, nested-forms

I did go through other similar topics and still was unable to solve my problem.
The following is my form code.

```
<div id="footer-left">
        <div id="subscribe">
            <form action="subscribe.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name" value="Enter Your Name"/>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="Enter Your Email"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

And the following my css code.

```
#subscribe {
        z-index:5;
    }
#footer-left {
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        bottom:0px;
        width:40%;
        height:350px;
        background:#f0f0f0;
        padding-right:2%;
        padding-left:5%;
        padding-top:50px;
    }
```

And-index-5 is highest among all classes and identifiers. Still my text area is not clickable.

I know I must be missing some small point but unable to know what it is.

And help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug or other browser developer tools to see what styles etc. are being applied to your inputs?

Comment: Inspect Element might show that something else is over the top of it.

Comment: Why are you using z-index? Is this a popup form?

Comment: if you reproduce the issue in jsfiddle would be better for us to identify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to reflect the solution.  In the original Fiddle posted in the comments, the z-index of the footer pane was -2.  This was affecting the child elements as well.  The form is now clickable after changing the z-index here to 3 as shown in the CSS below.  Full code is on the jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/cpTZT/2/

HTML

```
<body onload="scaleImage()">
    <div id="map_header" class="expressWay">
        <div id="header_tabs">
            <div id="header_left">
                <div id="logo_banner"></div>
                <div id="logo"><a href="./"><img src="./images/logo-text.png" style="width:100%;height:100%;" /></a>
                </div>
                <div id="tabs">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li id="city"><span>City</span>

                            <div class="dropDown">
                                <div class="column" style="margin-left:0px">    <a href="#">Bangalore</a>
    <a href="#">Chennai</a>
    <a href="#">Delhi</a>
    <a href="#">Mumbai</a>
    <a href="#">Hyderabad</a>
    <a href="#">Jaipur</a>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="header_right">
                <div id="social_links"> <a href="#" class="social_button" id="fb"></a>
    <a href="#" class="social_button" id="twt"></a>
    <a href="#" class="social_button" id="gplus"></a>
    <a href="#" class="social_button" id="pin"></a>

                </div>  <a href="#signIn" id="SignIn">Sign In</a>

                <img class="dots" src="./images/dots.png" align="center" style="display:inline-block;float:right;margin-right:40px;margin-top:10px;" />
                <li id="partner"><span>Partner With Us</span>
                </li>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="footer-left">
            <div id="subscribe">
                <form action="subscribe.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer-right-left">
            <ul>
                <li><b>COMPANY</b>
                </li>
                <li>About Us</li>
                <li>Careers</li>
                <li>Legal</li>
                <li>Terms & Conditions</li>
                <li>Press/Publications</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="footer-right-right">
            <ul>
                <li><b>CONTACT US</b>
                </li>
                <li>Street No XYX Locality City State,Pincode</li>
                <li>query@ananas.in</li>
                <li>+91-xxxxxxxxxx</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#footer {
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
    font-size:0.8em;
}
```

The area was clickable when I put the original code on JS Fiddle, but when you typed, the text did not disappear.

EDIT: Fixed the information to properly address the question.

Comment: I tried that but problem persists.
#footer-left is child of #footer

#footer {
 position:relative;
 z-index:-2;
 font-size:0.8em;
}

Comment: We need more context to see what the problem is then.  Perhaps try putting an !important tag on the subscribe class?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cpTZT/1/ the following is my code. Kindly look into it. There is a form at the footer m talking about.

Comment: See above please.   I changed my original answer to reflect the actual answer.  The only thing you'll need to change is the css for #footer.  The z-index of -2 was propagating to its children.  I changed this to 3 and it now works on the fiddle.